# Can I Make a while loop go in reverse?

Tags: java

I have 2 while loops which sets a shape to a certain colour then changes to the other colour and now I want it to go back to the original colour following the same principle to make it look like its spinning.

```
    public void spinShape()
   { 
      int shapeWidth = this.shape.getWidth();
      while (this.shape.getWidth() > 0)
      {  
         this.shape.setColour(BLUE);
         this.shape.setWidth(this.shape.getWidth() - 20);
         this.shape.setXPos(this.shape.getXPos() + 1);
         this.delay(2000);

      }


      while (this.shape.getWidth() < 100)
      {
         this.shape.setColour(GREEN);
         this.shape.setWidth(this.shape.getWidth() + 20);
         this.shape.setXPos(this.shape.getXPos() - 1);
         this.delay(2000);

      }
```

This code works to go from BLUE to GREEN now I want to go back to BLUE following the same +- 20 to make it look like its shrinking?

> change the colour of the shape to green if it is blue, or blue if it is green once it reaches its minimum width

and

> complete the second while loop condition to restore the shape to its width at the start of the method

Comment: Sure you can. Write some code that makes it do that.

Comment: Can you help me out?

Comment: I can give you a hint. The last sentence of your question contains an `if`. You need to put that in your code.

Comment: I worked out I need to use an 'if' statement just not sure where to put it or what statement needs to be aded as it won't let me use the colour

Comment: @M.Prokhorov can you please point me on where to go with it